# Recursion not working in blocks world problem ...not Backtracking to parent node

Tags: python, class, recursion, search, backtracking

```
import copy
class node:
    def __init__(self,state):
        self.state=state
        self.children=[]
    def action(self):
        for i in range(3):
                for j in range(3):
                    if i!=j:
                        temp=copy.deepcopy(self.state)
                        if len(temp[i])>0:
                            m=temp[i].pop()
                            temp[j].append(m)
                            if temp not in self.children:
                                self.children.append(node(temp))
    def display(self):
        print("different node \n")
        print(self.state)
        for i in range(len(self.children)):
            print(self.children[i].state)
            
    def search(self , goal,queue):
        print('called')
        if self.state==goal:
            print("inspection state=",self.state)
            return True 
        else:
            for i in range(len(self.children)):
                if self.children[i].state not in queue:
                    print(self.children[i].state)
                    self.children[i].action()
                    print(self.children[i].children[0].state)
                    temp=copy.deepcopy(self.children[i].state)
                    queue.append(temp)
                    return self.children[i].search(goal,queue)
                    return self.search(goal,queue)
            else:
                print("queue full error")
                
i_state=[['a'],['b','c'],[]]
root=node(i_state)
root.action()
goal=[[],['a','b','c'],[]]
queue=[]
root.search(goal,queue)
```

Here the code is not back tracing to parent node and searching other branches.
return self.children[i].search(goal,queue)
return self.search(goal,queue) sends the parent node to function when children fill up the queue of a particular branch

Comment: Welcome to SO! What problem is this supposed to solve? What's "blocks word problem" exactly?

Comment: its about stacking blocks a,b,c in right order.Here a link to it....https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocks_world

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this double `return` is the source of your problem:

```
return self.children[i].search(goal,queue)
return self.search(goal,queue)
```

The second statement will *never* be executed.  A typical way of handling this might be:

```
result = self.children[i].search(goal, queue)

if result:
     return result

return self.search(goal,queue)
```

Or whatever fits your algorithm.  Below is your code with this fix and some style changes:

```
import copy

class node:
    def __init__(self, state):
        self.state = state
        self.children = []

    def action(self):
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                if i != j:
                    if self.state[i]:
                        temp = copy.deepcopy(self.state)
                        m = temp[i].pop()
                        temp[j].append(m)

                        if temp not in self.children:
                            self.children.append(node(temp))

    def display(self):
        print("different node \n")
        print(self.state)

        for child in self.children:
            print(child.state)

    def search(self, goal, queue):
        print('called')

        if self.state == goal:
            print("inspection state =", self.state)
            return True

        for child in self.children:
            if child.state not in queue:
                print(child.state)
                child.action()
                print(child.children[0].state)
                temp = copy.deepcopy(child.state)
                queue.append(temp)
                result = child.search(goal, queue)

                if result:
                    return result

                return self.search(goal, queue)

        print("queue full error")
        return False

i_state = [['a'], ['b', 'c'], []]
root = node(i_state)
root.action()
goal = [[], ['a', 'b', 'c'], []]
queue = []
root.search(goal, queue)
```

Comment: Thanks main!! appreciate it. Recursion is new to me had problems in visualizing the flow.I took the idea of writing it next to each other from inorder traversal of trees data structure.